# Wait and get async data from global class Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm new in Vue and web programming. I have a problem with my Global Class in Vue. I have simple test for HTTP Request and save it to variable. The structure is :

• Main.vue

• Child.vue

• GlobalProps.vue

Child.vue :

```
watch: {
  dataPrepare: function() {
    console.log(this.dataPrepare, "watch"); //this execute before dataPrepare have value from HTTP request , so dataPrepare still empty

    this.$emit(`readDataPrepare`, this.dataPrepare); // pass to Main.vue
  }
},

mounted() {
  this.programProperties = ProgramProperties.data();

  (async() => {
    this.dataPrepare = this.getData("/getUser", {
      request: {
        token: "FFC35FAA7D70AD308FB74A6CD",
        username: "neka1"
      }
    });
    this.dataForm.date = (this.dataPrepare.data['date']);
    this.dataUser = this.mapDataInArray(this.dataPreparedata.Clist['c-list'], "usrnr", "usrname");
    console.log(this.dataPrepare, "after pars"); // this never execute
  })();
}
```

GlobalProps.vue :

```
Vue.mixin({
  methods: {
    ...
    getData(endpoint, bodyvalue) {
      const dataPayload = {
        data: []
      };

      (async () => {
        class HTTPError extends Error {}

        const response = await fetch(this.programProperties.host + endpoint, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(bodyvalue),
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
           dataPayload["data"] = {};

            throw new HTTPError('Fetch error:', response.statusText);
        } else {
            const parsed = await response.json();

            dataPayload["data"] = parsed;

            console.log(dataPayload, "Response " + endpoint + " : ");

        }
        // this.$emit(`emitDataPayload`, dataPayload);

        return dataPayload;
      })();
    }
  }
})
```

The problem is `dataPrepare` is not wait HTTP request. HTTP Request is on GlobalProps.vue. The flow I write in comment above. I need `dataPrepare` wait until the HTTP request is done.

If I write the HTTP request in Child.vue is work fine, but when I move HTTP Request in GlobalProps.vue I didn't get the data. Did I make a mistake? I read about this in the Vue documentation, but it did not help.

Comment: `getData()` should be the one returning a promise, if you want to await for its request to complete. Then, you can simply do `await getData()`.

Comment: @Terry thank you, I pull the return in `getData()` and I get the data from `dataPrepare`.

Comment: @Terry But why this line `console.log(this.dataPrepare, "after pars"); ` is still not execute?

Comment: I am not sure why you are wrapping all your async methods in IIFE. If that's the case the inner response from the awaited XMLHttpRequest never gets returned to the outer scope.

Comment: I need global method to HTTP request that return an object response. Do I do a mistake with this way?

Comment: In fact, you don't even need Vue to do that. Just create a file that exports a function that performs async requests, which returns a Promise with the response in the payload.